# Como criar objetos a partir de um arquivo de texto no Java?

Tags: java

Olá. Tenho uma classe no meu projeto (Pessoa) que contém atributos (por exemplo, nome, idade, sexo, etc) e possuo um array desses objetos (Pessoa). Tenho também um arquivo de texto e dentro dele está digitado várias características num formato Nome#Idade#Sexo, por exemplo Ana#20#Feminino numa linha, Paulo#31#Masculino na próxima. 
Gostaria de saber se há a possibilidade de quando o programa fazer a leitura desse arquivo txt, identificar que há uma String antes do carácter # e com isso gravá-la numa variável. Assim, eu poderia criar um objeto com as características do arquivo fornecido (tipo assim: Pessoa p = new Pessoa ("Ana","20","Feminino"). Com isso, eu identifico os atributos, crio objetos e coloco dentro do meu array.

Comment: Veja como ler arquivo texto: http://www.devmedia.com.br/lendo-dados-de-txt-com-java/23221. Depois, pra cada linha, use o método `linha.split("#")` para obter um array com o valor de cada atributo. Quando já tiver algum código, se não estiver funcionando bem, fica à vontade pra atualizar a pergunta e contar com a nossa ajuda.

Comment: @Caffé, não seria melhor fazer uma resposta com o seu comentário? pois acredito que seja a resposta da pergunta.

Comment: Fiz dessa forma e deu certo:
String result [ ] = line.split(“#”);
O comentário foi de grande ajuda, se quiser fazer uma resposta com ele eu aceito sem problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja como ler arquivo texto em Java:

[Lendo dados de Txt com Java](http://www.devmedia.com.br/lendo-dados-de-txt-com-java/23221)

Depois, para cada linha, use o método `linha.split("#")` para obter um array com o valor de cada atributo:

```
String atributosPessoa [ ] = line.split(“#”);
```